# With React-Intl, how do I fix error "Uncaught ReferenceError: No date format named: undefined"?

Tags: npm, reactjs, formatjs

Yahoo open-sourced a nice collection of internationalization tools for JavaScript, which they are calling FormatJS.

The [guide to FormatJS](http://formatjs.io/guide/) mentions that dates come with default formats `short`, `medium`, `long` and `full`.

FormatJS provides integrations for Dust, Handlebars, and React.

When using the React mixin (`React-Intl`) in a npm-managed environment, I can’t seem to format a number.

From my component, I call

```
this.formatDate(this.props.guide.get('date'), 'short')
```

However, I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: No date format named: undefined

My date is defined as 'short', which should be built-in. What gives?

Comment: I got a good answer here: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/34

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
{this.formatDate(this.props.guide.get('date'), {
    day  : 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    year : 'numeric'
})}
```

'short' is not built-in. It is decalred in the Render tab in  [guide to FormatJS](http://formatjs.io/react/) like this:

```
var intlData = {
"locales": "en-US",
"formats": {
    "date": {
        "short": {
            "day": "numeric",
            "month": "long",
            "year": "numeric"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation here suggests it’s built in. Scroll down just a bit and look at the four supposedly pre-defined date formats: http://formatjs.io/guide/#messageformat-formatted-argument • Here is [a screen shot of the documentation in question](https://www.dropbox.com/s/22wmvz750y4oftk/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-24%20at%201.58.00%20PM.png?dl=0)